# Scrapy - scrapy.exceptions.NotSupported: Unsupported URL scheme '': no handler available for that scheme

Tags: url, scrapy

I’m trying to scrap several pages from a website. 
For this, I’m using a loop to add the pages number of my URLs. 
I’ve got this error when I launch my spider.
I changed my quote to a double from a single or checked if I had spaces but the URLs seem to be well.

Do you have an idea of what’s wrong ?

**My loop**

```
> def url_lister():
>     url_list = []
>     page_count = 0
>     while page_count < 2: 
>         url = "['https://www.active.com/running?page=%s" %page_count + "']"
>         url_list.append(url)
>         print(url)
>         page_count += 1 
>     return url_list
```

**Here are the outcomes URLs**

```
['https://www.active.com/running?page=0']
-----------------------------
['https://www.active.com/running?page=1']
-----------------------------
["['https://www.active.com/running?page=0']", "['https://www.active.com/running?page=1']"]
-----------------------------
```

**Here is the message error**

```
2018-01-23 14:31:34 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['ACTIVE.pipelines.ActivePipeline']
2018-01-23 14:31:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-01-23 14:31:34 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-01-23 14:31:34 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-01-23 14:31:34 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] ERROR: Error downloading <GET :///robots.txt>: Unsupported URL scheme '': no handler available for that scheme
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tests, I changed my code and it works :

**Old code**

```
def url_lister():
    url_list = []
    page_count = 0
    while page_count < 2: 
        url = "['https://www.active.com/running?page=%s" %page_count + "']"
        url_list.append(url)
        print(url)
        page_count += 1 
    return url_list
```

**New code**

```
def url_lister():  
    url_list = []
    page_count = 0
    while page_count < 480: 
        url = 'https://www.active.com/running?page=%s' %page_count 
        url_list.append(url)
        page_count += 1 
    return url_list
```